# Why is checkbox changed twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do this:

```
  $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
    var current = $(this);
    $("label[for='" + current.attr("id") + "']").on('click', function() {
      current.change();
      alert('1');
    });
  });

  $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
    alert('2');
  });
```

Now, when I click on the label, the checkbox first alert(1) is showing up once, but the second(2) showing up twice. Can you tell me why? (The checkbox is hidden, seems like the change happens twice somehow)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to add a separate event handler for the `<label>` tag.  It will trigger the "click" on the `<input>`.

You're better off using "click" instead of "change" (especially with the newest jQuery). Old (perhaps new) IE versions don't trigger "change" on checkboxes until the focus changes.

*edit* the reason that the newest jQuery makes life better is that it fixes a long-standing bizarre "feature" of the library. Previously, programmatically triggering "click" would result in a call to any "click" handlers with the element in the state *before* the effect of the click took place. That is, if you call

```
$(myCheckbox).trigger("click");
```

and the element was checked, it would be checked in the call to the handler.  However, when a *real* click happens, the browser flips the state of the "checked" attribute *before* calling handlers.  That made life pretty weird, but as of 1.9 I'm pretty sure that's fixed.

Comment: older versions of IE (IIRC 7?) don't change the checkbox state when the label is clicked.

Comment: @zzzzBov I don't think that's true; IE7 certainly works, and I *think* IE6 worked. The main problem was that the "change" event isn't fired until the focus leaves the `<input>`.  However I don't have IE6 around anymore to try.

Comment: After a bit of testing using IETester, IE6 was the issue that I was remembering, and it's even more nuanced. `<label><input type="checkbox">Test</label>` does not work, while `<input type="checkbox" id="a"><label for="a">Test</label>` does (nesting with `[for]` also works). As pretty much no one uses IE6 anymore, my previous comment can safely be ignored.

Comment: @zzzzBov oh yes that's exactly right - I guess that's why my reptile brain always forces me to use `for` and not rely on nesting :-)

Comment: @zzzBov It's not exact. IE 7 won't trigger the change event when the label is clicked. Anyway, your point is interesting, I didn't know about the on change problems in the newest jQuery... What about radio buttons? would you recommend to use onClick?

Fyi, I use jquery 1.9, seems like the issue of clicking a checkbox is still not resolved(the change event is triggered twice). It's a little weird, as when it comes to radio buttons, they seem to behave as expected (only one change event)

Comment: @benams that's odd. I got into the habit of using "click" for both checkbox and radio buttons a long time ago, so I don't have much personal experience with how the "change" event behaves for those input types.  I've found that "click" works fine, except for that now-fixed jQuery behavior (which wasn't that much of a problem in practice).